# numpy arrays are inconsistent

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

When I try creating 2 numpy arrays with the only difference being their lengths, their shapes are different. I need a numpy array, with a shape

```
(20400, 520)
```

I am unsure why the bottom occurs. Any ideas what happened?

---

[image]

Comment: I did the exact same but it's not happening to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

My dataset had data points that weren't exactly 520 in length, so numpy was unable to create a 2d array from them. The error didn't happen from 0 - 1000 as the problematic data points were at ~6000.

---

**TLDR**: The length of some data points of `temp2` were inconsistent, forcing numpy to create a long 1D array instead of what I wanted, which was a 2D array.